# Удалить из строки элемент $parent

Tags: json, replace

Подскажите, как удалить все `$parent` из json строки:

```
{"children":[{"children":[{"children":[],"label":"33","value":"b7251ae3-4b17-4b24-b7a3-fc435e65f6f0","$parent":"~children~0"}],"label":"22","value":"9c5e53b8-29bf-4aee-b769-ec18a5225aa0","$parent":"~"}],"id":"b1a44191-b44c-4342-a646-70eec7de248f","label":"11","value":"a3010367-ba57-4e27-8e5e-6f3986501e7a"}
```

Comment: Уточните язык хотя бы.

Comment: javascript , :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  serialized = serialized.replace(/\$parent/g, '');
  serialized = serialized.replace(/\~/g, '');
  serialized = serialized.replace(/children0/g, '');
```